# Regularity and Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $F$ be a real function $2\pi$-periodic.

What is the lowest regularity that must be imposed on $F$ to admit a development in Fourier series ?

Comment: Are you looking for pointwise convergence, a.e. convergence, convergence in $L_2$, Cesaro summability, ... ?  There are continuous functions where the Fourier series diverges at a point.  [Carleson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) is a one very general result - very difficult to prove

Comment: thank you very much , ibut what we can say if $F$  is a distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a Fourier series for an object $f$, you must be able to give a meaning to 
$\left<f, e^{in(\cdot)}\right>$. This is possible for any generalized function on the circle.

Now if you want the series to converge to $f$, you need to specify the type of convergence: $L^2$, $L^1$, pointwise, etc. And each of these will have different requirements.